# How to train a Regression model for single input and multiple output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have trained a regression model that approximates the weights for the equation :
**Y = R+B+G**
For this, I provide pre-determined values of R, B and G and Y, as training data and after training the model, the model is successfully able to predict the value of Y for given values of R, B and G. I used a neural network with 3 inputs, 1 dense layer (hidden layer) with 2 neurons and the output layer (output) with a single neuron.

```
    hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=[3])
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
```

But, I need to implement the inverse of this. i.e., I need to train a model that takes in value of Y and predicts values of R, B and G that corrspond to that value of Y. 
I have just learnt that regression is all about a **single** output. So, I am unable to think of a solution and the path to it. 
Kindly Help.
(P.S Is it possible to use the model that I have already trained, to do this? I mean, once, the weights have been determined for R, B and G, is it possible to manipulate the model to use these weights to map Y to R, B and G?)

Comment: Do you wish to colorize the images using their RGB values? If yes, there's another way to do it.

Comment: No, I dont mean to do that. I am trying to approximate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to start solving your problem using neural network in tensorflow.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model

X=np.random.random(size=(100,1))
y=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,3)).astype(float)   #Regression

input1 = Input(shape=(1,))
l1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input1)
l2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(l1)
l3 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(l2)
out = Dense(3)(l3)

model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=[out])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=['mean_squared_error']
    )

history = model.fit(X, [y], epochs=10, batch_size=64)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Kudos to You! But how is it possible? I mean regression that gives multiple outputs.... Please explain, I am very curious.

Comment: The model internally learn the mapping function. Like any other decision making problem, a subset of the neurons in the network contributes more for a particular decision node of output layer whereas another set may be more influential for other.

Comment: I have 2 doubts: 1) Why is the format of X and [y] different? Why not X and y?                                                                              2) I have been following tensorflow tutorials recently and they try to imply that regression is ONLY for single output scenarios. Are they wrong?

Comment: Regarding (2), they are not wrong if they have **not** explicitly claimed so (and indeed they haven't); keep in mind that tutorials usually deal with simple introductory settings, and multiple output regression is not such a setting

Comment: 1. List of outputs is normally used for multi output model while instantiating Model. However, single output can also be used in a list as i did `outputs=[out]` when i instantiate Model, therefore, the true label is passed in the similar fashion, i.e. `[y]`, though `y` will work.
2. Here, the hypothesis is that multiple decision/output variables are dependent on same input(s) set. Hidden units, abstract representation in another (higher/lower) dimensional feature space, are contributing towards decision with variable weight which is learnt from training samples by the model.

Comment: Thank you so much @desertnaut and **bit01** for all the efforts. One last thing: kindly refer me to the resources that can help me understand the back-end of such multiple-output regression models. Much of the regression resources focus primarily on linear regression for single output.